# Curvature defined as $k(t) = \frac{\|T'(t)\|}{v(t)}$, explanation of the proof

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation, chain-rule

I have problems to understand how it's derived the formula for the curvature $k(t) = \frac{\|T'(t)\|}{v(t)}$.

The derivation starts with the equality $$\frac{dT}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{dT}{dt}$$

where $T$ is the unit velocity vector for the curve  and $s$ is the arc length function for the curve.

So $$\frac{dT}{ds} = \frac{T'(t)}{v(t)}$$

and from here it's all clear to me how to finish.

---

Initially I supposed it was just an application of chain rule, but if I rewrite the proof in Netwon's notation I obtain

$$[T(s(t))]' = T'(s(t))s'(t)= T'(s(t))v(t)$$

So to get the final equality I should have $[T(s(t))]' = T'(t)$, but is it always the case ?

I don't know if it is useful the fact that $T(s(t))$ and $T(t)$ have the same trajectory (in general they differ for a certain value of $t$ though). Is this enough? Why?

Comment: You are using $v$ here to mean speed and not velocity.  But $T$ seems to be sometimes a vector and sometimes a scalar, please clarify.

Comment: $T$ is a vector equal to velocity/speed, and yes here $v$ denotes speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leibniz notation obscures what's going on. If everything is functions of $t$ and we reparametrize the curve by arclength, getting $\alpha(t) = \tilde\alpha(s(t))$, then $\alpha'(t) = \tilde T(s(t))\upsilon(t)$ and $T(t) = \dfrac{\alpha'(t)}{\|\alpha'(t)\|} = \dfrac{\tilde T(s(t))\upsilon(t)}{\upsilon(t)} = \tilde T(s(t))$. Now the chain rule gives
$$T'(t) = (\tilde T\circ s)'(t) = \tilde T'(s(t))\upsilon(t) = \tilde k(s(t))\upsilon(t),$$
so
$$k(t)=\tilde k(s(t)) = \dfrac{T'(t)}{\upsilon(t)}.$$

Comment: I think in your argument it's implicit that $\|\tilde\alpha'(s(t))\| = 1$, right? But why can I be sure a parametrization with this property exists?

Comment: That's an arclength parametrization, yes. It exists for any regular parametrized curve. If your text doesn't prove this, download my (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: oh thanks a lot! Anyway Leibniz's notation obscures most of the proof!

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the confusion here is due to sloppy notation. $T(s)$ and $T(t)$ are two *different* functions (one takes in arc length parameter $s$, and the other takes in your arbitrary parameter value $t$) and the meaning of $T'$ will differ depending on which function you're differentiating.

If we make things more explicit, by naming the two functions $T(s)$ and $\tilde T(t)$ for instance, with
$$T(s[t]) = \tilde T(t)$$
then differentiating both sides by $t$ gives you the necessary identity,
$$\frac{dT}{ds} \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{d\tilde{T}}{dt}.$$